# accessing direct message on twitter via passport-twitter nodejs library

Tags: node.js, passport-twitter

I'm using mean stack which comes with passport-twitter libarary for connecting to twitter. 
passport uses   `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate`  which does not gives access to direct messages.

How do I get access to twitter's direct messages via passport-twitter library?

here is a twitter strategy

```
passport.use( new TwitterStrategy({
        consumerKey: config.twitter.clientID,
        consumerSecret: config.twitter.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: config.twitter.callbackURL
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        User.findOne({
            'twitter.id_str': profile.id
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                user = new User({
                    name: profile.displayName,
                    username: profile.username,
                    provider: 'twitter',
                    twitter: profile._json
                });
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    return done(err, user);
                });
            } else {
                return done(err, user);
            }
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: `passport` designed for user authorization, and accessing direct message have nothing to do with it. In `twitter` case it's `OAuth2` authorization, so you can use its `accessToken` to access twitter API. But you'll need another node.js library to do so.

Comment: any other library which can do both? because It is not getting access token too.

Comment: Actually, I worked a lot with `passport-facebook` and facebook API, but not with twitter. As for the `accessToken`, it should be in `token` variable.